# What is this tool with a metal strip mounted perpendicular to a wooden handle?

Tags: tool-identification

What is this tool?  It is 9 inches long, with a straight wooden handle and a flat wooden head with one rounded and one flat edge.  In the flat edge of the wooden head is a thick strip of metal which protrudes by half its width, offering a blunt/flat edge.

It feels sufficiently strong and has the right sort of heft that conceivably it could be used to strike something using the metal part — perhaps some sort of soft sheet metal like lead flashing.[image: The toon in question]

[image: Another view of the tool]

Comment: Again, where was this found? Do you have any context for it or the other tool [you're asking about](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/14026/what-is-this-tool-that-looks-a-bit-like-a-dough-scraper-but-with-a-sharp-cutting)? What else was with them? Do you know their origins? Anything would be helpful.

Comment: *"conceivably it could be used to strike something using the metal part — perhaps some sort of soft sheet metal like lead flashing."* Just to reiterate the point I made in your other Question, if this were the case it would not make this a suitable query for the Woodworking stack. Tool IDs here are for woodworking-related tools only, regardless of what they happen to be made from, not for things that are just made from wood or have wooden components.

Comment: @MattDMo
As with the other tool and question referenced in both of your comments, I found this tool with a collection of woodworker's tools in a woodworking toolbox and therefore considered it likely that it was a woodworking tool itself, or at least a tool used by a woodworker.

@ Graphus
Does the fact that I asked the question here not at least suggest to you that I think it is a woodworking tool?  I do realise that my guess in the question suggests otherwise; this was misleading, and I should perhaps have said "nevertheless I think it is a woodworking tool" to preempt your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a *veneer hammer*.

The hammer part of the name is confusing as these aren't a percussion tool, they are instead pressing tools. They are used in traditional veneer work (using hot protein-based glue) to firmly press the veneer down onto the substrate as the glue cools and gels, a process called "hammer veneering".

This one could be a commercially made version or a user-made tool, not sure if it's possible to tell as if you go back far enough the shape and materials could be the same, and the quality of fit and finish could be indistinguishable. It does however look very much like the pattern suggested by Robert Wearing in his books on jig/tool/accessories making (which could originally have come from the pages of **The Woodworker** magazine).

A little on hammer veneering for anyone interested:
[**Hammer Veneering**, Veneer the whole world, without clamps](https://www.finewoodworking.com/membership/pdf/36984/011010052.pdf) (PDF warning) by Tage Frid from Fine Woodworking, originally published 1978.
[Hammer Veneering](https://www.popularwoodworking.com/techniques/hammer-veneering-2/) by Don Williams on Popular Woodworking.

Comment: Thanks very much, both for the answer itself and the links to additional info.

Comment: You're most welcome.