# What is this tool that looks a bit like a dough scraper but with a sharp cutting edge?

Tags: tool-identification

What is this tool?  It has a turned wooden handle atop a large straight blade with a semicircular cutout for the fingers.  The blade is 7 inches long and 4 inches deep.

Were it not for the cutout from the blade and were the blade not sharp, it could be used as a dough scraper.  Since the blade is sharp but not very long and has 90 degree corners, I assume it is intended to cut down through something relatively soft with a pushing action (as opposed to a slicing action back and forth).

There is a damaged label on the handle, which looks as if it may read (with "_" marking unclear letters) "_ICH_ST____ADE".

I am asking this here because I acquired the tool amongst a set of woodworking tools in a joiner's box and as such consider that it is may be a woodworking tool or a least a tool used by a woodworker.

[image: The tool in question]
[image: Another view of the tool, with the lable visible]

Comment: Where was it found?

Comment: Why did you ask this here if even you didn't think it was a woodworking tool? (We don't answer queries on things that just happen to have wooden parts.) Voting to close.

Comment: @ MattDMo
@ Graphus 
I asked it here because I acquired the tool amongst a set of woodworking tools in a joiner's box and as such consider that it is may be a woodworking tool or a least a tool used by a woodworker. I will add that information to the question.

Comment: From what I've seen of cooking utensils, both modern and historical, I wouldn't be at all surprised that this was indeed a dough knife/dough scraper. We can't infer from the fact that it now has a pronounced edge that it did originally (any more than blunt edges or rounded corners on surviving tools suggests they were always that way). There's a long history of tools being modified/adapted for personal preference, and even an entirely different use to what was originally intended, and this does extend into cooking utensils — including dough scrapers converted into herb choppers or push knives.

Comment: Quite so — maybe that is the case this time, although I'm still curious as to what it has been turned into, if so, and why it was where I found it.  Of course, it's always possible that someone else put it there in the intervening time, without knowing themselves what it is.

Comment: It looks like it was intentionally sharpened, not just having acquired the edge through years of use. In that case, I would bet that it was actually used as a woodworking tool, even if it was designed to be used in the kitchen. I'm also curious about what it was used for in the shop. Perhaps slicing thin wood like veneer? This especially makes sense when considering that you [also found a veneer hammer](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/14025/what-is-this-tool-with-a-metal-strip-mounted-perpendicular-to-a-wooden-handle) in with the lot of tools.

Comment: It could also have been used for working with balsa. Just because the owner was a joiner doesn't mean they didn't have a hobby, like making model airplanes...

Comment: @MattDMo, yep it could indeed have been adapted to cut veneer, I actually had the same thought (although it would need to be sharpened *very* well to be effective in this role, at least as sharp as a chisel). However it could just as easily have been modified for someone with ageing hands to more easily chop herbs, or portion ice cream blocks for the kids, or cut tofu.... we can but speculate. However the key point as far as the SE is concerned would be the same in all cases,

Comment: @Graphus, as you rightly said above, we can't read too much into how sharp the blade is now; nevertheless it is — perhaps appropriately, given that it does seem after all as if this is a repurposed kitchen item — about as sharp as most people's kitchen knives, which is to say sharp enough to cause a nasty cut but not sharp enough to be of much use in the kitchen.

Comment: *"about as sharp as most people's kitchen knives, which is to say sharp enough to cause a nasty cut but not sharp enough to be of much use in the kitchen"* LOL, you've been in a lot of the same kitchens as I have it seems! Except for serrated knives virtually every other household I've been in there's a drawer full of blunt knives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a "[herb chopper](https://thevintagekitchenstore.co.uk/en/slicing-chopping/90-her.html)" to me

[image]
Pictured are a variety of antique herb choppers. Two of them look a lot like the tool you have - the two in the middle against the wall.

There are a variety of styles for herb choppers. There is no standard design for a herb chopper.

When I search for "vintage herb chopper" I get some results that a good match for your tool.
When I search for "dough scrapers" or "vintage dough scrapers" I get no results that look like your tool.

It's reasonable to assume it's a woodworking tool since you found it amongst other woodworking tools.
However, as my wife would confirm with an annoyed tone of voice, sometimes kitchen tools find their way into my toolbox.

Comment: Thanks.  I am accepting this answer based on the very similar looking herb chopper in the included picture.  That it might be a herb chopper hadn't occurred to me, as I was only previously familiar with the demi lune sort represented in the bottom right of that picture.  As noted in this answer and in comments to the question, it seems at least plausible that somebody did use this in a woodworking context, but it looks as if what I have here is indeed a kitchen utensil that has been repurposed or misplaced.